# Error when adding dependency to play scala.build file

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

i am working on an akka project with java and play framewrok.

I want to build a cluster system with akka remote clustering.

but after adding the dependencies to the build.scala file

I get the following error.

```
[info] Done updating.
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/util/FiniteDuration
```

this is the code from the build.scala file

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "akka-remote"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT" ,
          "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT" ,
         "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-kernel" % "2.1-SNAPSHOT"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here 
        resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"
    )

}
```

can anyone help out of this problem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest stable version of Play!

Play! framework 2.0.x is shipped with Akka 2.0.2 **but not with Akka remote**.
To add it just use:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.0.2" ,
      "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote" % "2.0.2" ,
      "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-kernel" % "2.0.2"
)
```

If you need of logging feature you can add also

```
 "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j" % "2.0.2"
```

If you use 2.1 Akka release with Play! 2.0.x serie maybe you obtains some conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Akka is already shipped with Play framework: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/project/Build.scala#L280

But the embedded version is not the latest one (Akka 2.0.2 for Play 2.0.3).

If you add the latest Akka version, you'll may hit some lib conflict.

And as your problem, your dependendy version (2.1-SNAPSHOT) does not exist in the Typesafe `releases` repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor/

You have to use the Typesafe `snapshots` repository:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
    resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots"
)
```